# Are linear combinations of random vectors linear independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

If I have $n$ **random** vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$, they are linear independent with high probability.

What can be said about linear combinations of these vectors? I.e. does for $n$ different linear combinations of the form $$y_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}x_j$$ with $a_{i,j}\in\mathbb{R}$ for $i,j=1,\ldots,n$ follow, that $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ are linearly dependent with high probability?

**Edit:** The entries of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are supposed to be identically distributed on [-b,b] with $b\neq\infty$.

Comment: Are the coefficients $a_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}$ random as well?

Comment: HINT: This is the same as asking whether $$\det (a_{i,j}) \neq 0$$ has high probability. Well, the determinant could be anything, so intuitively the probability that $\det =0$ is $0$.

Comment: Strictly speaking this question makes no sense, since you need to specify a probability measure on $\Bbb R$. There is no obvious choice.

Comment: @lukkio Yes, let's assume that. Otherwise it would be possible to find $a_{i,j}$, so that $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ just span a one dimensional space.

Comment: I think that with "random" Rob meant "uniformly distributed" in their domain.

Comment: @lukkio: The domain is $\Bbb R$. There is no uniform measure on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: You're right, sorry.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen That's absolutely right, please assume a continuous and uniform distribution on [-b,b], with $b\neq\infty$.